# Python - Expected a character buffer object?

Tags: python, email, imap

I have the following code:

```
import imaplib
import email
import codecs
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('email@gmail.com', 'pass')
mail.list()

mail.select("inbox") 

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
i = len(data[0].split())

for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
    result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = email_data[0][1]
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    save_string = str("/Users/Me/Desktop/Email/" + str(x) + ".txt") 
    myfile = open(save_string, 'a')
    myfile.write(email_message)
    myfile.close()
```

(I am trying to export all the email as a txt file.)

I get the error `expected a character buffer object`.

Does anyone know why this would be?

Thanks

Edit: Error is in line `myfile.write(email_message)`

Comment: Stacktrace please. In which line does the exception occur? Oh, and is it python 2 or python 3?

Comment: I guess this happens because `email.message_from_string(raw_email)` is not returning a string, but a `Message` object instead.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have added that line. It's Python two. (I think :( )

Comment: @PedroFerreira I see. Does anyone have any idea how I'd change this? I thought it was a string.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message

see `as_string`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`email.message_from_string(raw_email)` is not returning a string, but a `Message` object instead. You cannot write `Message` objects directly to a file without serializing them in some way.

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is to convert `email_message` to a string.

```
myfile.write(str(email_message))
```